# How to stop windows 8 from wanting to scan and repair a drive every single boot

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, boot

Every time I reboot my laptop windows is running the scan and repair utility on a non-essential hard drive, problem is it gets stuck and last 3 hours before it boots. The only way I can interrupt that is if I hard shutdown the computer (hold the power button for 5sec). How do I stop that, I tried `chkntfs /x e:`
to no avail.

Comment: You should let it finish.

Comment: @DavidPostill: If the Windows 8 feature behaves anything like the equivalent feature in Windows 10, letting it finish may not be a viable option, given that the scan and repair feature has a tendency to get stuck indefinitely (for days ...).